# A bilinear diophantine problem

Tags: diophantine-equations, bilinear-form

Suppose we know $a,b,c,d,e,f,m\in\Bbb Z$ in $$(a^2c+b^2d)y+ab(vy)+(a^2e+b^2f)v=m$$ how do we find $v,y\in\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Multiply through by $4ab,$ then add a constant term to both sides so that the left hand side becomes an evident product.

Comment: the $4$ seems not needed.

Comment: $(a^2c+b^2d)y+ab(vy)+(a^2e+b^2f)v=m\implies ((a^3bc+ab^3d)y+a^2b^2(vy)+(a^3be+ab^3f)v)=mab$ how does this yield product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $$ PQxy + Rx + Sy, $$ take
$$ P^2 Q^2 xy + PQR x + PQSy. $$ Compare
$$ (PQx +S) (PQy+R ) =  P^2 Q^2 xy + PQR x + PQSy +RS$$

So, in your original problem, multiply both sides by $ab,$ then add something useful to both sides

Comment: so $(abv+(a^2c+b^2d))(aby+(a^2e+b^2f))=abm+(a^2c+b^2d)(a^2e+b^2f)$

Comment: it seems easier than factoring right? we have $(\gamma_1 v+ \mu_1)(\gamma_2 y+ \mu_2)=m'$ where $v,y\ll m$.

Comment: by this I mean the unknowns are smaller than factors

Comment: @Student. I don't know about easier, unless you intend for all quantities to be positive. Even then the improvement may not be massive. Recommend you find a way to solve large numbers of problems with constants of small to medium size, and keep careful score of how hard it was to solve, under different restrictions on the constants. I solve tons of problems on computer, it teaches me things, and sometimes the outcome suggested by the computer can be proved; not always, of course.

Comment: yes all are positive. it somehow seems to be easier but not sure how